CronTrigger runs thread before actually specified time
I have ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduled by CronTrigger and observe quite strange thing. I run a simple task in it, that just prints the current date and time. Like that:
public class MyCron {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCron);

    private final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;
    private final CronTrigger cronTrigger;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> runnableTask;

    public MyCron(String cronEntry) {
        this.scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        this.scheduler.setPoolSize(10);
        this.scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("MyCron-" + name + "-");
        this.scheduler.initialize();
        this.cronTrigger = new CronTrigger(cronEntry);
        runnableTask = scheduler.schedule(this::workerThread, cronTrigger);
    }


where this::workerThread prints a date and time. But I observe it runs a little bit earlier that scheduled, like for the cron strings 0 */5 * * * * and 0 */7 * * * * I observe the following:
mycron  | 2024-05-30T17:59:59.844Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 2-7] c.e   : Cron test 2 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 17:59:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:04:59.785Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:04:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:06:59.702Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 2-7] c.e   : Cron test 2 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:06:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:09:59.785Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:09:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:13:59.702Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 2-7] c.e   : Cron test 2 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:13:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:14:59.784Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:14:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:19:59.785Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:19:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:20:59.665Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 2-7] c.e   : Cron test 2 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:20:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:24:59.746Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:24:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:27:59.692Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 2-7] c.e   : Cron test 2 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:27:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:29:59.783Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:29:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:34:59.694Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 2-7] c.e   : Cron test 2 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:34:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:34:59.783Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:34:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:39:59.782Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:39:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:41:59.694Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 2-7] c.e   : Cron test 2 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:41:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)
mycron  | 2024-05-30T18:44:59.790Z  INFO 1 --- [n-Cron test 1-1] c.e   : Cron test 1 worker is running: Thu May 30 2024 18:44:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)

I don't understand how is it possible and why could this happen. Am I doing something wrong?
My versions are: Running with Spring Boot v3.3.0, Spring v6.1.8
Thank you!
Update: I see a close request because question is unclear. I supposed it's pretty clear but I'll try to explain it further anyways. As I specified CronTrigger's seconds set to zero, I expect my scheduler will run at zero seconds, not on 59th second. This is the least. Another side is, that if I set it to run on every 5th minute, I expect it to run on 18:05:00, not on 18:04:59. Here's the link to javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html#parse(java.lang.String)
Update/explanation - why is it important:
In my task, i run a sql query with where condition like where timestamp < current_timestamp() As it runs within container, it performs really fast and condition is not triggering. Quite strange, is it such a rare case?

Why do you think it is running earlier?

Why, mostly because I specified it to run on every 5th and 7th minutes

Your cron expressions are invalid "0 */7 * * * *" , Cron expression don't support day of week and day of month at the same time. Here is a valid cron expression every 7 mins : "0 0/7 0 ? * * *"

@AnotherOne it's not a cron, as I wrote, it is CronTrigger https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html#parse(java.lang.String)

0 */5 * * * * ==> every 5 minutes. Try 0 0/5 * * * *

@Khanna111 Sorry, didn't get your point. Could you elaborate please?

@Khanna111 Like, what I mean - first '0' means 'at every 0th second' And what I observe - seconds, as you could see in the log, are equal to 59

Well, according to the issue 29735, they consider it's not a bug. So, I added the code like that to the task as a workaround
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long fraction = now - now / 1000 * 1000;
if (fraction > 500) {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000L - fraction);
}

A bit too ugly and smelling, but I see no other solutions as they don't want to fix it.

The implementation of

CronExpression

rounds to a second. So it cannot guarantee the execution precisely at that second (every 0th second).
From the logs, you can see that the milli second value is being rounded to the nearest second. So even though it displays 59 as the second value, the ms are rounded up and "every 0th second" is true.

Could you please share the source of this information?
